# Can an iOS 7 app access either device camera without user knowledge?

Tags: privacy, ios

This statement in the iOS 7 release notes implies that non-China devices do not need user consent:

> iOS now requests user consent for apps to use audio input on all iOS
>   7 devices. For devices sold in China, iOS will also request user
>   consent for apps to use the camera hardware.
>   [iOS SDK Release Notes for iOS 7 GM](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-7.0/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013202-CH1-SW4%5D)

Is there any protection against an app accessing either camera without the user's knowledge and/or consent?

This is a follow-up question to the comment on device fingerprinting (and other iOS privacy vulnerabilities) here:
[What unique fingerprinting information can an iOS7 app collect?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/48439/what-unique-fingerprinting-information-can-an-ios7-app-collect#comment78620_48439)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As of iOS 8, apps do need to request access to the cameras**. When an app on iOS 8 attempts to access a camera, it shows a system alert and requests the user to accept the access before the app is allowed. Denying the access will prohibit the app from accessing the camera.

For iOS 7 in your question, yes, an app can access either camera without requesting the user's permission (except in China as you found out). All apps have unrestricted access to view the camera feed of either the front-facing or rear-facing camera and take pictures/videos.

However, access to the Camera Roll to save such media does require the user's consent. Most apps on the App Store request access to photos immediately so as to not interrupt the user whilst they take their first picture, however this is simply to gain access to the general location for saving the media, not for accessing the camera itself. Apps are fully able to capture pictures and video from either camera at will without requesting permission providing it saves the media within the app's sandbox.

Comment: Do I understand correctly then that any (active) 3rd-party app could potentially take still photos or videos surreptitiously, and phone them home to a server on the internet, with no indication whatsoever to the user?

Comment: @pseudon Exactly, providing the media is kept within the sandbox.

Comment: Thanks. Scary, and hopefully this vulnerability is closed by Apple soon.

Comment: @pseudon Updated answer! iOS 8 beta *does* show a request alert for camera access

Comment: George, thanks, I noticed the "worldwide" reference in the WWDC privacy session slides http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/715xx4loqo5can9/715/715_user_privacy_in_ios_and_os_x.pdf?dl=1 A welcome change!